# cake 1.3 element enable/disable cache

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-1.3

my elements looks like that:

```
echo $this->element('myelement', array('cache' => array('key' => 'myUniqKey', 'time' => '+1 hour')));
```

when i have Configure::write('Cache.disable', false); in my config file, all elements are chaced, but when i have Configure::write('Cache.disable', true); my elements from layout are in cache and elements from view aren't

can You tel me is it normal?
can i cache my elements from view without turning cache on?

Comment: wouldnt you say that's logic? and your actions not so much? why would you disable the cache if you want to use it?

Comment: i want to cache only elements... no queries, no views, no models... only elements

Comment: well, then you dont have to call the caching stuff anywhere else. but you still have to enable it once in your core.

Comment: it's not so simple... if cache is turned on in config but not coled anywhere, it still doing something more than saving my elements. It affects loading models in controller so i want to have it turned off in config